# Cauchy-Schwarz Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was reading a direct proof of the inequality. The beginning goes like this:

> We rescale $u$ and $v$ to new vectors which have the same length; namely $\Vert v \Vert \cdot u$ and $\Vert u \Vert\cdot v$

I don't understand this part. How do these two vectors have the same length?

If $u$ and $v$ are distinct vectors, and $\Vert u \Vert = k_1$ and $\Vert v \Vert = k_2$ then how is $k_1u = k_2v$ ?

Comment: The length of $a u $ is $a ||u||$ for scalar $a$. Consequently, $|| ~||v|| u~|| = || ~||u|| v~|| = ||u|| ~||v||$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\frac{u}{||u||}$ and $\frac{v}{||v||}$ are both unit vectors that they share the same length 1. Multiply both vectors by $||u||\cdot||v||$ and you will get $u\cdot||v||$ and $v\cdot||u||$.

Comment: Could you explain why this is intuitively correct? What you wrote makes perfect sense but I can't seem to figure out why this is.

Comment: It's just what stochasticboy321 have commented. Try to calculate norm of $u\cdot ||v||$ and $v\cdot ||u||$ then you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example, suppose $u$ has length $2$ and $v$ has length $3$.  Then $3u$ and $2v$ both have length $6$.